# How do I call function in another functions parameters?

Tags: c++

Can I call functions in function parameters?

```
void Function_1() {
    //some code
}

void Function_2(void* Using_Function()) {
    //some code

    Using_Function();

    //some code
}

int main() {
    Function_2(Function_1);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: **What book did you read about C++?** See [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Consider using [lambda-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`<functional>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional)

Comment: Are you asking how to _pass a function_, as a parameter?

Comment: Of course that's possible. You can use `std::function` and lambda expressions, function pointers, callable classes with overloaded `()` operators. Be more specific please!

Answer (score 7):

I think you are asking about *function pointers*, if so then like this.

```
void Function_1() {
    //some code
}

void Function_2(void (*Using_Function)()) {
    //some code

    Using_Function();

    //some code
}

...

Function_2(Function_1);
```

Comment: Note: This is the old C-style way and modern C++ should use `std::function` for it's extra flexibility.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: I'd mostly disagree. `std::function` can be useful in certain cases, but its flexibility comes at a cost, so unless you actually need the extra capabilities it provides, it's better avoided. For the case at hand, a pointer to a function is completely adequate.